# How to execute MongoDB findAndModify query in MongoCollection Java driver 3?

Tags: java, mongodb

MongoDB 2.5 driver have `DBCollection.findAndModify()` method for this, but `MongoCollection` misses this method. After some search, I found that `findOneAndUpdate()` now has the same role.
But this method has different signature, don't understand how to use it. Here is command I want to execute

```
db.COL1.findAndModify({
  query: { id: 2 },
  update: {
    $setOnInsert: { date: new Date(), reptype: 'EOD' }
  },
  new: true,   // return new doc if one is upserted
  upsert: true // insert the document if it does not exist
})
```

Documentation for [`findOneAndUpdate` method](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/client/MongoCollection.html#findOneAndUpdate-org.bson.conversions.Bson-org.bson.conversions.Bson-com.mongodb.client.model.FindOneAndUpdateOptions-) states that

> Returns:
>       the document that was updated. Depending on the value of the `returnOriginal` property, this will either be the document as it was before the update or as it is after the update.

but cannot find anything about this `returnOriginal` property. Anyone knows how to set it correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Java equivalent of your query should go roughly like this:

```
Document query = new Document("id", 2);

Document setOnInsert = new Document();
setOnInsert.put("date", new Date());
setOnInsert.put("reptype", "EOD");
Document update = new Document("$setOnInsert", setOnInsert);

FindOneAndUpdateOptions options = new FindOneAndUpdateOptions();
options.returnDocument(ReturnDocument.AFTER);
options.upsert(true);

db.getCollection("COL1").findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options);
```

Regarding the `returnOriginal` property - you're right - there is no such thing.  The javadoc is irrelevant in this place. However, there is a `returnDocument` property in [FindOneAndUpdateOptions](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/client/model/FindOneAndUpdateOptions.html#returnDocument-com.mongodb.client.model.ReturnDocument-). You can set it to `ReturnDocument.AFTER` or `ReturnDocument.BEFORE` which is equivalent to `new: true/false`.

Comment: `returnOriginal` flag should be `new FindOneAndUpdateOptions().returnDocument(ReturnDocument.BEFORE))`

Comment: @chridam isn't the `ReturnDocument.AFTER` an equivalent of `new: true`?

Comment: Whilst that is true in that context, I'm referring to what the OP asked in their question _but cannot find anything about this `returnOriginal` property. Anyone knows how to set it correctly?_

Comment: @chridam ah, I see. I'm going to update my answer and explain it.

Comment: Yeah, I think the OP wants the `returnUpdated` option